# Use Entries fieldtype functionality in plugin populated by REST api data

Tags: plugin-development

Is it possible to use the Entries FieldType widget in my plugin and populate the modal with data from a third party REST API?

Comment: Can you explain more what you're trying to achieve? Not following from your existing description.

Comment: I am wanting to use the Categories/Entries field type widget in my plugin with the model data originating from third party REST api. So when the user clicks the "Add a cateogory" button the modal will show the data from the third party api and because it is using that same fieldtype widget they can select multiple items.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have basically the same problem now in Craft3: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28749/element-type-vs-field-type-or-element-type-without-database-storage If you have found a solution to your problem, I would be very glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 3):

You are speaking of the Element Selector Modal. It is javascript and available to use by third-party devs, but the code is specific to Craft Elements (Entries, Assets, Users, etc.). I don't think you'll get it to work with information polled from a third-party API.

There's a post about it in the Craft Dev Google+ group (invite only), but I'm not sure if the info exists anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I found the post on the Craft Dev Google+ group.  I guess I will need to create the same functionality and use Garnish for the modal.

Comment: @aran Could you post the URL to the post on the Craft Dev Google+ group?

Comment: @Magne are you apart of the Craft Dev Google+ group (invite only)? If so you can search for "Element Selector Modal" it would be the post with the most comments.

Comment: @aran I'm afraid I'm not. I only found this: https://plus.google.com/communities/106505340287442511226/s/Element%20Selector%20Modal