# Element type vs. Field type - or: Element type without database storage?

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, custom-fieldtype, elementtype, custom-field

I have already searched for information on this topic but I did not find much. I hope I did not overlook something.

**My problem is the following:** I want to try to write a plugin that lists entries from an external service via API calls. I have already done this in Craft2 with a custom field type (a dropdown-field) that listed all available elements.

Now for Craft3, I want to go one step further and implement a Modal like the AssetPicker where the user can list elements in a table or thumbnail view or even search for one.

Making the API-calls is easy. Nothing to fancy there. However, I struggle with how to integrate it into craft and how to do the templating.

I started with a custom FieldType like I did the last time. **However, I am not sure whether it would be better to use an Element Type?** As far as I understand, Element Types store their entries in the database, which I do not plan to do, since I access a remote database via an API. I only want to store the item-id in my custom field. On the other hand, I have the feeling that there are already available functions like  `Craft.createElementSelectorModal()` that implement many functions I need and work great with custom Element Types.

I do not yet totally understand the concepts of element types and field types and how they differ. If you have good sources of documentation, I am also thankful for that, especially information on how to use the ElementSelectorModal. I did not find much information about this.

### In summary:

- Would you suggest using a custom field type or custom element type?
- Is it possible to use custom element types without storing everything in a database?
- Do you have any good resources of information on these topics?
- Do you have good resources of information about the ElemetSelectorModal?

Thank you so much for your help.

If I did overlook an answer to my question, already available on this platform, please feel free to refer to it.

## Update

I have read a lot now about modals, for example:

- [Is it possible to use the ElementType Modal UI for a custom Field Type Plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/895/is-it-possible-to-use-the-elementtype-modal-ui-for-a-custom-field-type-plugin)
- [How can my plugin generate a generic modal window in the Control Panel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-can-my-plugin-generate-a-generic-modal-window-in-the-control-panel/384#384)
- [Possible to override Garnish.Modal? [Plugin]](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/possible-to-override-garnish-modal-plugin)

And I found this post, which almost exactly describes my problem: [Use Entries fieldtype functionality in plugin populated by REST api data](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7094/use-entries-fieldtype-functionality-in-plugin-populated-by-rest-api-data), however, some of the linked entries are not accessible to me and it referred to Craft 2.0, not version 3.

I understand that I can build my own modal using the Garnish-code. However, I would love to use the already existing functionality of the element type-modal. Therefore my question is:

- **Is it possible to define a custom element type without a database storage connected to it?**

I considered copying all API-results into the database and update it regularly by a cronjob. However, this duplicated the content from the external source which is unnecessary in my eyes. I would rather love to "populate" a custom field type "on the go" by a API-call, without writing it to the database. Is there any way to do this?